# returning a string from an if statement from another class

Tags: c#

My code returns an error in my public static string ValidateCreditScore(int creditscore, string status) that A local or parameter named "status" cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter.

basically I just want to return that statement so I can place it in my placeholder where it says "{0} is {1}, applicantName, applicant.status.
I want the statement to say the name and say wheater the credit score is acceptable or not.

my question is do I even need the string status in my public static string ValidateCreditScore(int creditscore, string status) since I'm already passing the credit score into it? or do I need it because I am returning something...

```
using System;

public class MortgageApplication
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int creditScore = 0;
    string applicantName = "";
    char userInput = 'n';
    string status = "";

    Console.WriteLine("** CSCC Mortgage Company **");
    Console.Write("\nWould you like to run this program [y, n]? ");
    userInput = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    while (!(userInput == 'n'))
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the applicant's name: ");
        applicantName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter credit score: ");
        creditScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        try
        {
            Applicant applicant = new Applicant(applicantName, creditScore, status);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", applicantName,applicant.status);
        }

        catch (ArgumentException anyException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(anyException.Message);
        }

        Console.Write("Would you like to run this program [y, n]? ");
        userInput = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Please press the <enter> key to terminate the program.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}

public class Applicant
{
public Applicant(string name, int creditscore, string status)
{
    Name = name;
    CreditScore = creditscore;
    status = ValidateCreditScore(creditscore, status);
}

public string Name { get; private set; }
public double CreditScore { get; private set; }
public string status { get; private set; }

public static string ValidateCreditScore(int creditscore, string status)
{
    try
    {
        if (creditscore <= 299 && creditscore >= 851)
        {

            throw new ArgumentException("Value does not fall within the expected range.");

        }

        if (creditscore <= 649)
        {
            string status = Convert.ToString("not accepted");
            return status;
        }

        if (creditscore >=650 )
        {
            string status = Convert.ToString("accepted");
            return status;
        }

    }

    catch (ArgumentException anyException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(anyException.Message);

    }
    return "Not Accepted";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because one of the variables passed into `ValidateCreditScore` is named "status"

```
public static string ValidateCreditScore(int creditscore, string status)
```

but then you try to create another variable with the same name later:

```
if (creditscore <= 649)
{
    string status = Convert.ToString("not accepted");
    return status;
}
```

rename one of the variables to something else and it should work.

Also, the `Convert.ToString()` is not needed and you don't need to store the string in a variable before you return it. So the above lines become

```
if(creditscore <= 649)
{
   return "not accepted";
}
```

Lastly, it looks like the status that is passed into `ValidateCreditScore` isn't even used in the function, so you can get rid of it.

Comment: I did your recommendations and while it compiles it will out put the name is and then blank afterwards...would you understand why that would be?

Comment: It is because you have another same named variable problem. Your `Applicant` constructor passes in a status string, but you also have a class level string property called status. The one that is being set in the constructor is the one passed into the constructor, which goes out of scope when the constructor returns. Remove the status parameter from the `Applicant` constructor and it should set the right one.

In the meantime, I suggest studying scope. You can probably find some good articles by Googling "c# variable scope"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are passing a variable named `status` into your method, but then you are also trying to declare a variable with the same name. You don't even need to declare the variable in the method, you can rewrite your code like so:

```
    if (creditscore <= 649)
    {
        return "not accepted";
    }

    if (creditscore >=650 )
    {
        return "accepted";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the status parameter in your method ValidateCreditScore.
Just return the string without having to use a variable like:
...

```
return Convert.ToString("accepted");
```

or

```
return Convert.ToString("not accepted");
```

So remove that parameter in the method and fix the build errors.